# Use SQL files in Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, orm

I'm a fan of [Yesql](https://github.com/krisajenkins/yesql)-style templates that consist of raw SQL with placeholders for parameters.

Here is an example from the docs:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE country_code = ?
```

This snipped is stored in a file and pulled into the application like so:

```
(defquery users-by-country "some/where/users_by_country.sql")
(users-by-country db-spec "GB")
```

Is there any gem with the same functionality in Ruby? Or is there a way to at least load raw SQL from a file and execute it, storing the result in an array or json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, and this (a separate SQL file) is a good technique for longer queries. Any of the database adapter gems can do this.  In `pg`, which I'm most familiar with,

1. Read your query from a SQL file, e.g. `File.read`
2. Open a connection, e.g. `PG::Connection.open`
3. Call `exec_params`

Example from `pg` documentation:

```
require 'pg'
conn = PG::Connection.open(:dbname => 'test')
res = conn.exec_params('SELECT $1 AS a, $2 AS b, $3 AS c', [1, 2, nil])
# Equivalent to:
#  res  = conn.exec('SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b, NULL AS c')
```

http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html

As you can see, the placeholders here are sequentially numbered, an improvement on simple question marks, I think.

Comment: As an aside, Yesql's [latest version](https://github.com/krisajenkins/yesql/tree/v0.5.0-beta2) has named parameters.